# How to Update/Migrate SQLite database with EF on Azure

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using an SQLite database for my application. On desktop I can easily run `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` when needed.

Now that I'm further developing the database and features while the site is live I need to run `Update-Database` on the server, but I don't know how to do that.

Is there a piece of code that I can run during start up that will update the database?

Due to my subscription I don't have Azure Storage or access to the command line, so that's out of the option.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if you think it resolved your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `DbContext.Database.Migrate()` in `Configure` method of `Startup` class. This will automatically migrate your SQLite database on application start if there are pending migrations.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    ...
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(...));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    using(var context = new MyDbContext(...))
    {
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and apologies for the late reply. I've tried adding this to Startup, ConfigureServices and Configure by adding `DbContext db` as method param and then `db.Database.Migrate()` in method (only way that didn't highlight syntax errors) and all 3 methods failed, crashing the application on startup with 3 different errors.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Ah, Thank you. In meantime I've come up with a simpler solution, but this one works as well so I'll mark it as answered. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DethoRhyne, could you share your solution? I'm having the same issue with this one. Is it substantially different than this answer?

Comment: @DanMihalea Hi Dan, sorry but I can't help you with this. I've lost the project some time ago and I don't remember what I've done to sort this out.